# image processing toolbox already installed still Undefined function 'extractHOGFeatures' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am executing the following code in matlab.

```
ver
img = imread('/usr/local/MATLAB/coursera_svm/10.pgm');
[featureVector, hogVisualization] =extractHOGFeatures(img);
```

output:

```
MATLAB Version: 8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)
MATLAB License Number: 
Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-51-generic #69~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:32:41 UTC 2015 x86_64
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
MATLAB           Version 8.6         (R2015b)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 7.0         (R2015b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.5.2       (R2015b)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 6.0         (R2015b)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.3.2       (R2015b)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.10        (R2015b)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.3         (R2015b)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.4         (R2015b)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 7.3         (R2015b)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.7         (R2015b)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 7.1         (R2015b)
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox               Version 10.1        (R2015b)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 6.3         (R2015b)
```

> **Undefined function 'extractHOGFeatures' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.**

Can some one please help me in solving this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extractHOGFeatures` is a part of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, which you seem to have installed...  What do you see if you do

```
>> which extractHOGFeatures
```

If it tells you that `extractHOGFeatures` is not found, do this:

```
>> rehash toolboxcache
```

and try it again. If that doesn't work, there maybe a problem with the license for the Computer Vision System Toolbox. You may want to contact your system administrator, or call Mathworks tech support.

See the documentation for [rehash toolboxcache](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/toolbox-path-caching-in-the-matlab-program.html).

Comment: Sorry, it's "rehash", not "reset".

Comment: @Dima This is the output:

    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/toolbox/vision/vision/extractHOGFeatures.m  % Has no license available

Does it mean, image processing tool is installed on my machine but doesn't have license ?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like your institution or company has a limited number of floating licenses and they are all being used at the moment. Definitely check with your system administrator.